# How do I select some items having same value in 0th position from a 2D list in python

Tags: python-3.x, multidimensional-array

I want to separately store adjacency list for all the nodes from a graph.How can I do this? 
Like if there are 7 vertices I want 7 lists containing arcs emanating from ecah and every node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does it have to be a list? Why don't you use [numpy](http://www.numpy.org/) to create an **adjacency matrix**.

If you want to use lists, you should first know that there is **no such thing** as a 2D list in python. The closest thing you can get is if you put the 7 lists inside another list list like this:

```
list1 = [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]  # represents the edges connecting node 1 to the rest
list2 = [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1]  # same thing for node 2
list3 = [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0]  # node 3
# and so on until we have 1 list for each node

adjacency_list = [list1, list2, list3, list4, list5, list6, list7]  # each element is a list

# To see if there is an edge between node 2 and node 3:
print(adjacency_list[2][3])  # 3rd element of the 2nd list 
# in this case it will return 0
```

If the graph is not directed you can use the indices of the inner and outer lists interchangeably.